# Sum of 2 different non matching columns from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

This s my first question on SO, so please bear if I am not super clear! I am trying to sum up values of 2 columns from 2 tables. Both table values have a common ID called 'imid'.  These imids are further divided as 'pmid' (say 1 imid can have one or  multiple pmids). Both tables have different structures. I would want to sum values on 1 column from table1 and another column from table(to use it for a php calculation). When I try JOIN it always gives me a timeout error. Query below.

```
SELECT  F.`imid` AS imid, SUM( F.Impression ) AS si, D.accmgr AS accmgr, D.cmname AS cmname,sum(D.Item_Impression_Cap) AS sim
FROM trasactions F, rawdata D
WHERE F.`imid` = D.`imid`
AND F.EntryDate LIKE '2017-%-%' 
GROUP BY D.`imid`, F.`imid` ORDER BY F.`imid` ASC
```

I get results, but not even close to the correct numbers.(eg) Impression as 6,557,824 instead of 1,233,287 for a particular imid.

Not sure where I am wrong! Any help would be great...

Edit: Thanks for the responses...I managed to write the query...

```
SELECT  F.`imid`, F.si , F.imname,D.Item_Start_Date ,D.sim,  D.Item_End_Date, D.accmgr, D.cmname 
FROM (SELECT `imid` AS imid, SUM(Impression ) AS si, adname AS imname, EntryDate  FROM trasactions GROUP BY imid) F LEFT JOIN
(SELECT imid,Item_Start_Date, Item_End_Date, accmgr AS accmgr, cmname AS cmname, sum(Item_Impression_Cap) AS sim FROM rawdata GROUP BY imid) D ON    F.`imid`=D.`imid`
WHERE D.cmname IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY F.`imid`
ORDER BY F.`imid` ASC
```

Now there is a new question! I am doing some calculations based on the array values derived from the query above...(eg) `$pacing = $row['si']/$avgday*100;`

Say I am listing the 'Pacing' for all items active. Would it be possible to count values from variables. (eg) Would want to show the count of items where $pacing is less than 100%. Would it even be possible to do that!! Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to SO..what is the error shown

Comment: Please share table structure..